# About the usage of "In order to", is this sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I was learning English with my friends. Basically everyone has to construct a sentence with the new words learned on that day.

We were trying to learn the grammar by constructing sentences and judging each others. This is the sentence from one of my friends:

> As an administrator, in order to end the relentless bothering from my friend, I admonished him.

I try to correct this sentence to:

> As an administrator, I admonished my friend in order to end the relentless bothering from him.

and I thought I was correct. So am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possibly correct, but the meanings are different.

In the first example.  I (the administrator) admonished him (an unknown man) so that my friend (a different person) would stop the relentless bothering (of me)

In the second case I (the administrator) admonished my friend (an second person) so that he (my friend) would stop the relentless bothering (of me).

The use of "bothering" like this is acceptable in casual speech, but it wouldn't work well in a formal context. I might go for:

> As the administrator, I admonished my friend to stop him from bothering me relentlessly.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer!